# C++ - proper way to map objects (like strings) to member functions in table

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, functor, pointer-to-member

I'm processing events defined by a 3rd party API.
The events are identified by string identifiers i.e. `"EventABC"`

I need to map these (string) events in a table to member-functions of an object.

**QUESTION**

What's the safest and cleanest way to do this?

Comment: How do you know which object to call those member functions on? Or should this map be different for each instance of the object?

Comment: I would guesss `std::mem_fun()` although I have never used it, I always use a table of `std::function`, populated with lambdas which have captured their `this` pointers.

Comment: @MaxLanghof there's only one object. It holds all the handlers. The map would be the same as there's only one instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without further constraints, this is easily accomplished with a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` from `std::string` to `std::function<void()>`. With C++11 you can use lambdas to unobtrusively capture the `this` object to call the member functions on.

```
class HandlerHandler
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> handlers;

    void foo();
    void bar();
    void frobnicate();

    HandlerHandler()
    {
        handlers["FOO"] = [this](){ foo(); };
        handlers["BAR"] = [this](){ bar(); };
        handlers["FROB"] = [this](){ frobnicate(); };
    }

    void handle(std::string h)
    {
        handlers[h]();
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nbygdF

You may want to guard against the case of `h` not being present in the map (currently it will throw an exception as it tries to call a default-constructed function).

Answer (score 1):

Can do something like below, wrap the methods in std::function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

struct Target
{
    void member1() {
        std::cout << "member1\n";
    }

    void member2() {
        std::cout << "member2\n";
    }
};


int main()
{   
   // events will be called on this object
   Target myTarget; 

   std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> table;
   table.insert({"member1", std::bind(&Target::member1, &myTarget)});
   table.insert({"member2", std::bind(&Target::member2, &myTarget)});

   std::string event = "member2";
   table[event]();
}
```